# Style QComboBox's sub-control down-arrow when mouse is hovering over the QComboBox via QSS

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qtstylesheets

I know how to style `QComboBox` when mouse is hovering by doing:

```
pComboBox->setStyleSheet(pComboBox->styleSheet()+QString("  QComboBox:hover{css style here}"))
```

And I also know to style `QComboBox`'s sub-control down-arrow's style via:

```
pComboBox->setStyleSheet(pComboBox->styleSheet()+QString("  QComboBox::down-arrow{css style here}"))
```

But I don't know how to style `QComboBox`'s sub-control `down-arrow` when the mouse is hovering over the `QComboBox` via `QSS`.  Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know is `QSS` powerful enough to do this(I think no), but with `eventfilter` you can do this very easy:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{

    if (obj == ui->comboBox && event->type() == QEvent::Enter)
    {
        //user enters combobox, so we apply stylesheet
        ui->comboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox::down-arrow{background-color: red}");
    }
    else
        if(event->type() == QEvent::Leave)//user leaves combobox, so we set default settings
            ui->comboBox->setStyleSheet("");

    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

To use `eventFilter` you should also:

```
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);//in header
```

and

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);//in constructor
```